# Drupal 8, new module installation redirecting me to the Update manager page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

Am trying to install my first module to the Drupal 8. When I click on Install Module, Drupal is redirecting me to the http://localhost/drupal-8.7.1/core/authorize.php page.

When I am working on my local environment, why Drupal needs FTP connections. Any configurations am mising, this is completely new local dev environment.

This page needs FTP *username*, *password*, *hostname* and *port* , this is the error am getting after redirection.

> Failed to connect to the server. The server reports the following
>   message: Cannot connect to FTP Server, check settings
>
> For more help installing or updating code on your server, see the
>   handbook. WARNING: You are not using an encrypted connection, so your
>   password will be sent in plain text. Learn more.

Edit 1: 
I tried to post on drupal.org but Drupal 8.* version is not getting listed under Version dropdown. I can see only 7.* in version dropdown.
https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drupal

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data sites/default`

step 2 : `sudo chmod -R 775 modules`

step 3 : `sudo chmod 777 www -Rf`

it works for me..,

Comment: This is very insecure. https://www.drupal.org/node/244924